# Progress bar Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having an aspx file and an ascx file(Details.ascx). In my ascx file, I am having the following code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var a = document.getElementById("HidStatus").value;
        var b = parseInt(a);
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: b,
            max: 100
        });
    });
    
</script>

 <fieldset>
    <div id="progressbar" style="height: 8px; float: left; padding: .3%; margin-right: 274px;
        margin-left: auto; width: 300px;">
    </div>
    <div id="Div1" style="float: left; margin-left: 300px; margin-right: 100px">
        <%= Html.Hidden("HidStatus", (double)ViewData["StatusBar"])%>
        <%= Html.Label(Convert.ToString(ViewData["StatusBar"] + "% Completed"))%>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

In my aspx file....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Load() {
        $.ajaxSettings.cache = false;
        var Id = document.getElementById("Id").value;
        if (Id != null && Id != "") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "../Test/Populate",
                data: "&Id=" + Id.toString(),
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg != null && msg != "") {
                        alert(msg);
                        //document.getElementById("TargetId").innerHTML = msg;
                         $('#TargetId').html(msg);
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                },
                error: function (msg) { }
            });
        }
    }
   
</script>


<div class="content-admin">
    <div class="form-content">
         <div id="TargetId">
            <% Html.RenderPartial("Details"); %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the first time, the progressbar got loaded..Whenever I made selected index changes, the progress bar disappears...

I think,this line `document.getElementById("ProvideFeedbackDetailsTargetId").innerHTML = msg;` may be the reason for issue...But dont know what to do....

How to solve this...

Comment: document.getElementById("ProvideFeedbackDetailsTargetId").innerHTML+=msg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using jQuery. Could you change all your document.getElementById() calls to
jquery calls like

```
document.getElementById("TargetId").innerHTML = msg;
```

will be in jquery:

```
$('#TargetId').html(msg);
```

This could be starter for solving the issues, also debugin with firebug on firefox could help.

Comment: Hi, i had updated by code...See source code above..By giving like this whenever i made selected index, blank screen is displayed.